# Representations of the form $\varphi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ vs $\phi: G \rightarrow Aut(A)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Standard representation theory studies homomorphisms of the form $\varphi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space.

How much does the focus of representation theory change if one considers instead homomorphisms of the form $\phi: G \rightarrow Aut(A)$ where $A$ is an abelian group?

If the aim is to study a complicated object by comparing it to the automorphisms of a simpler object, then the choice of abelian groups (no scalars) instead of vector spaces would make sense.  Now both these cases are covered in the broader context of modules over noncommutative rings, but I'm certain each subarea has its own flavor.  What are the pertinent differences, or are representations of the later type only studied in the broader context of modules?

Comment: Representation theory is specifically about tying together group theory and linear algebra. The reason being that groups are notoriously difficult to study in general but if we look at representations in terms of (invertible) matrices, we have all of the theory of linear algebra at our disposal.

Comment: I would disagree that abelian groups are simpler than vector spaces.  Isomorphism classes of finite dimensional vector spaces are indexed by the nonnegative integers, for example.  Isomorphism classes of finitely generated abelian groups are indexed by lists of prime powers.  Automorphisms of vector spaces are given by invertible matrices.  Automorphisms of an arbitrary abelian group are much more complicated (see, for example, http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605185.pdf)

Comment: The next best thing to a module over a field (ie a vector space),  is a module over an integral domain.  When that integral domain is Z, one gets an abelian group.  Here a good portion of linear algebra is still applicable.  Representations focusing on abelian groups is an obvious modification to try, and given the myriad varieties of "representations" out there I would hardly call them exotic or outside the perview of representation theory.  We are just talking about modules over noncommutative rings here, nothing bizarre.

Comment: Now automorphisms of abelian groups may not be simpler than linear transformations, but there is one advantage: the availability of finiteness arguments.  Regardless of this issue, however, the fact remains that every group has a representation of this sort and their study can't readily be avoided. So, then... what are the basic facts known so far and where would one get a start on the topic?

Comment: Edit: finitely generated abelian groups are indexed by lists of prime powers for the torsion part and a nonnegative integer for the free part.  One nice thing about vector spaces is there is no torsion, for example.  I would argue that free abelian groups are easier to understand than torsion abelian groups (namely their automorphism groups are easier to identify).  In this case, finiteness (in the sense of a finite set) goes out the window.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really know the answer to your question, and I'm not trying to dissuade you from pursuing it, I just disagree that it's an easier problem.

Comment: What you are describing is merely a group acting on another object $A$ in a reasonable fashion. One can study this for many reasons (perhaps you might be more interested in $A$, or, as in some cases, the induced crossed product). Perhaps you could elaborate on what your goals are.

Comment: First, I have no goals here, besides curiousity about what I see as a blatantly straightforward generalization.  Second, I concede that in most (but not all) respects 'representations' of the latter form are harder to deal with.  Third, I think morphisms of the second type above definitely fall under the umbrella of representation theory... Note that quaternions force their way into the topic of rep. theory fairly readily.  If we drop commutativity on the one hand, why not consider dropping the existence of inverses on the other?  One could argue that Z is more essential in mathematics than H.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The representation theory of groups —even the "standard" one— includes in a very prominent way the *integral* representation theory, very much so, and has always done so.

Representations on abelian groups, and more generally on modules over other rings (like $p$-adic numbers and such) show up all over the place, even if you are ultimately interested only in representations on vector spaces. For example, in order to establish the connections between the representation theory of a group over fields on characteristic zero and the theory over fields over positive characteristic one uses very prominently the representation theory over rings which are not fields.

On the other hand, lots of representations that one finds in nature are not on vector spaces but appear naturally on abelian groups. For example, Galois groups of number fields act naturally on the respective rings of integers, and that action has much more information that the action of the group on the field itself. Every time you have an action of a group on a topological space you get induced actions on the homology and cohomology of the space. Etc.

---

Usually introductions to representation theory deal only with representations over fields, but if you pick the classic bible on the subject by Curtis and Reiner, you will find integral representations very prominently. Likewise, Auslander and his school worked (whenever they could do it successfully) at the level of artin algebras, which are objctes more general than algebras over fields.

---

What happens, though, is that when you represent things on abelian groups (or, more generally, modules over some base ring) and not on vector spaces is that things do get more complicated: the fact that vector field form a semisimple category is used **all** over the place when studying representations on vector spaces.

A good exercise is to try to classify the representations of cyclic groups on finitely generated torsion-free groups, that is, on groups of the form $\mathbb Z^n$. This is quite more difficult than the same problem over fields!

Comment: A search on 'integral representation theory' gives a lot of dated/copy-protected material.  These days does the term denote the study of representations on R-modules for arbitrary rings R, or are other conditions on R assumed?  I would guess that the theory simplifies dramatically if R must be an integral domain and all the more so if R is in fact the integers.  Does it?

Comment: If you assume more things you get more structure.  Of course.

Comment: "dated"?! ${}{}$

Comment: Okay... perhaps I should have said "pre-LaTex".  :)

Comment: "the classic bible on the subject by Curtis and Reiner" That's not a unique description :)